# Choice of a square root

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, complex-numbers

I am writting an article and i want to fix a choice for a square root of a complex number:

The square root that i want to choose satisfies

$(\sqrt{z})^2=z$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\sqrt{z}=\sqrt{z}$ if $z\in\mathbb{R}+$ and $\sqrt{z}=i\sqrt{-z}$ if $z\in\mathbb{R}-$

How can i explain that in the begining of the article ? I am not very good in english and i don't now how to formulate that once a time for all the article.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those conditions still gives you a variety of choices.  For example you could still be unclear as to whether $\sqrt{-i}$ is $\frac{\sqrt{2}}2 - i \frac{\sqrt{2}}2$ or $-\frac{\sqrt{2}}2 + i \frac{\sqrt{2}}2$.  One approach  is to define $\sqrt{re^{i\theta}}=\sqrt{r}e^{i\theta/2}$ with $r \ge 0$ and (you choose) either $0 \le \theta \lt 2\pi$ or $-\pi \lt \theta \le \pi$

Comment: can you please edit your comment it is not clear

Comment: which one i choose to assume that $(\sqrt{-i})^2=-i$?

Comment: Both will give you $(\sqrt{z})^2=z$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$

Comment: How to formulate a sentence explaning that  for negative real numbers we want $\sqrt{r}$ to be $i\sqrt{-r}$ for all the article? have you a an idea?

Comment: this is what i wrote: The square root of a complex number $z=re^{i\phi}$ with $r\ge 0$ and $0\le \phi<2\pi$ is defined as follows: $\sqrt{z}={r}e^{i\frac{\phi}{2}}$. does that saficient to understand that i want  $\sqrt{-2}=i\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: You may have a typo and may have intended $\sqrt{z}=\sqrt{r}e^{i\frac{\phi}{2}}$.  But that would then be sufficient. You will have $\sqrt{-2}=i\sqrt{2}$ but not $\sqrt{(-2)^2}=-2$

Comment: that give $\sqrt{(-2)^2}=2$ and $(\sqrt{(-2)})^2=-2$ No?

Answer (score 1):

The universally accepted convention (which isn't universally known) is that for positive real numbers the square root sign means the positive root. If you must, you can tell your readers that for negative real numbers $r$ you want $\sqrt{r}$ to be $i\sqrt{-r}$. You can just say that at the start.

*For complex numbers with an imaginary part it's a bad idea to use the square root sign since there is no good convention for choosing one of the square roots over the other.*

Related: [Order of operations with complex numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2670522/order-of-operations-with-complex-numbers/2670551#2670551)

Comment: What do you recommend in place of the square root symbol?

Comment: @BarryCipra I don't think there's a good alternative, for good reason. You can use the  square root symbol (or an alternative like the $1/2$ power) only if later on it doesn't matter which square root you take and you say so up front - perhaps because the result is squared, or input to another even function. Otherwise you really must come to grips with multivalued complex functions to some extent.

Comment: I'm inclined to disagree. The square root symbol (and/or the "^{1/2}" notation) is quite useful as a well-defined function, as long as you are upfront and clear as to the convention being used, and then take care to adhere to the implications of the chosen convention. I did my PhD dissertation (ages ago) on modular forms of half integral weight. In his seminal 1973 paper on the subject, Goro Shimura picked a particular convention and stuck to it. His paper (and my dissertation) would have been unwieldy to write without a square root notation.

Comment: @BarryCipra OK I'm convinced, at least for professionals. But the number of questions on this site that hinge on misuse mean beginners should be cautious.

Comment: I agree. The notation is beguiling, and even professionals sometimes succumb to its charms.

Answer (score 0):

The conventions $\Re(\sqrt z)\gt0$ for $z\in\mathbb{R}^+$ and $\Im(\sqrt z)\gt0$ for $z\in\mathbb{R}^-$ are almost always adopted for a square root function. After that, there are two standard conventions:

$$\Re(\sqrt z)\gt0\quad\text{for }z\not\in\mathbb{R}$$
or
$$\Im(\sqrt z)\gt0\quad\text{for }z\not\in\mathbb{R}$$

The first of these introduces a discontinuity in the complex-valued function $f(z)=\sqrt z$ at every point on the negative half of the real axis; the second does the same at every point on the positive half of the real axis.